# How to execute a job that needs a job that was skipped in github actions

Tags: if-statement, github-actions, jobs, skip, jobexecutiondecider

below workflow has 4 jobs.

I want job `conditional-job` to execute no matter whether the jobs it depends on are skipped i.e. `skip-job` and `build`.

Please let me know if and how is it possible.

```
name: My GitHub Actions Workflow

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: This job runs only on pull requests
        run: echo "JOB name build"    

  deploy:
    if: ${{ false }}  
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: This job runs only on pull requests
        run: echo "JOB name deploy"    
      # Your deployment steps go here...

  skip-job:
    if: ${{ false }} # This job will never run
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: This job is skipped
        run: echo "This job won't run because the if condition is set to false"

  conditional-job:
    needs:
      - skip-job  # This sets the 'skip-job' job as a dependency
      - deploy   # This sets the 'deploy' job as a dependency
    if: ${{ true }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: This job runs only on pull requests
        run: echo "JOB name conditional-job"
```

Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use expression `needs.skip-job.result == 'skipped' || needs. deploy.result == 'skipped'`

If you are not sure about result value you can print it before adding condition

```
  conditional-job:
    needs:
      - skip-job  # This sets the 'skip-job' job as a dependency
      - deploy   # This sets the 'deploy' job as a dependency
    if: ${{ true }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: This job runs only on pull requests
        run: echo "JOB name conditional-job"
      - name: check result
        run: |
         echo 'needs.skip-job.result'
         echo 'needs.deploy.result'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to run your job after another job only when it's successful or skipped, you need to add them as `needs`. It makes the job wait for the other job. Then need to use `if` to make it conditional. Also, ensure you have `always()` alongside with other conditions.

```yaml
name: build

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo build

  skipped:
    name: Skipped
    if: ${{ false }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo skipped

  conditional:
    needs: 
      - skipped
      - build
    name: Conditional
    if: |
      always() && 
      (needs.skipped.result == 'skipped' || needs.skipped.result == 'success') &&
      (needs.build.result == 'skipped' || needs.build.result == 'success')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: echo ${{ needs.skipped.result }}
```